# \scriptstyle does not work in multline environment

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontsize

Consider the following beamer code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \vspace{-1.5cm}
    Result:
    \begin{align*}
    \pi_1(k, i\w) &=- \left( \frac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} - \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \pi_2(k,i\w) &= \left( \frac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \Pi_1(k, i\w) &= \begin{dcases}
     -\frac{\e_{q,R}^2}{\e_{q,R}^2 + \w^2}, & q \sim 0 \\
    {\scriptstyle
    \begin{multlined} 
    \frac12 \left[ -\frac14 \log((\e_{q'R}-2D)^2 + \w^2) - \frac14 \log((\e_{q'R}+2D)^2 + \w^2) + \frac12 \log(\e_{q'R}^2 +\w^2) \right.\\
    \left.\quad -\frac12 i \left( \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}-2D}{\w} + \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}+2D}{\w} \right) \right]
    \end{multlined}
}
    , & q \sim 2k_F     
    \end{dcases}.
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is an overfull equation as in the picture:
[image]

Why the `\scriptstyle` does not work, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`multlined` uses `\displaystyle`. On the other hand, `\scriptstyle` is bad because fractions will have numerators and denominators in `\scriptscriptstyle` so the subscripts will turn out to be too big. Better splitting the last parenthesis and use one more line, all in `\textstyle`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, amsmath}

\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon}
\newcommand{\w}{\omega}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Result:
    \begin{align*}
    \pi_1(k, i\w) &=- \left( \frac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} - \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \pi_2(k,i\w) &= \left( \frac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \Pi_1(k, i\w) &= \begin{dcases}
     -\frac{\e_{q,R}^2}{\e_{q,R}^2 + \w^2}, & q \sim 0 \\
      \begin{aligned}[b]
      \textstyle
      \frac12 \Bigl[
        &\textstyle - \frac14 \log((\e_{q'R}-2D)^2 + \w^2) \\
        &\textstyle - \frac14 \log((\e_{q'R}+2D)^2 + \w^2) \\
        &\textstyle + \frac12 \log(\e_{q'R}^2 +\w^2) \\
        &\textstyle - \frac12 i \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}-2D}{\w} \\
        &\textstyle - \frac12 i \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}+2D}{\w}
    \Bigr],
    \end{aligned}
    & q \sim 2k_F     
    \end{dcases}.
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I left the trailing dot, but, as you see, it's hanging from nowhere.

Answer (score 4):

For fun, with use the `rcases` defined in the `mathtools` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\w}{\omega}
\newcommand*{\e}{\epsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Result:
    \begin{align*}
    \pi_1(k, i\w) & = -\left(\frac{1}{2} \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} - \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \pi_2(k, i\w) & =  \left(\frac{1}{2} \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \Pi_1(k, i\w) &= \\
    \MoveEqLeft[2.4]{\begin{dcases}
     -\frac{\e_{q,R}^2}{\e_{q,R}^2 + \w^2}\raisebox{2.4pt}{ ,} & q \sim 0 \\
     \begin{rcases}
    \frac{1}{2}\biggl[
        - \frac{1}{4} \log\bigl((\e_{q'R}-2D)^2 + \w^2\bigr) \\
    \quad\,
        - \frac{1}{4} \log\bigl((\e_{q'R}+2D)^2 + \w^2\bigr)
            + \frac{1}{2} \log\bigl(\e_{q'R}^2 +\w^2\bigr) \\
    \quad\,
        - \frac{1}{2} i \Bigl( \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}-2D}{\w} + \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}+2D}{\w} \Bigr) \biggr]
    \end{rcases}
    , & q \sim 2k_F
    \end{dcases}}
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need  `\scriptstyle`, which is not very readable. I suggest to split the `dcases` environment into 4 lines, and nest it in a `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath`(to be loaded *before* mathtools). Also, I used the medium-sized fractions from the latter package for the fractionary coefficients:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\newcommand*{\w}{\omega}
\newcommand*{\e}{\epsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \vspace{-0.5cm}
    Result:
\begin{fleqn}
    \begin{align*}
    \pi_1(k, i\w) &=- \left( \mfrac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} - \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \pi_2(k,i\w) &= \left( \mfrac12 \log\frac{D^2+\w^2}{\w^2} + \tan^{-1}\frac{D}{\w} \right) \\
    \Pi_1(k, i\w) &= \\
    \MoveEqLeft[3]{\begin{dcases}
     -\frac{\e_{q,R}^2}{\e_{q,R}^2 + \w^2}, & q \sim 0 \\
     \begin{aligned}
    \mfrac12\biggl[ & -\mfrac14 \log((\e_{q'R}-2D)^2 + \w^2) \\
     & - \mfrac14 \log((\e_{q'R}+2D)^2 + \w^2)+ \mfrac12 \log(\e_{q'R}^2 +\w^2) \\
     & -\mfrac12 i \left( \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}-2D}{\w} + \tan^{-1} \frac{\e_{q'R}+2D}{\w} \right) \biggr]
    \end{aligned}
    , & q \sim 2k_F
    \end{dcases}.}
    \end{align*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]